# Computing Shortest Distance using Google Map v3 and Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps, routing, google-maps-api

How to compute shortest route between two points in **google map** that user selects and provide all routes from source to destination in **Transport system**?

Answer (score 5):

you can achieve this with Google Maps JavaScript API v3 - Directions Service. There is a doc [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions?hl=tr-TR). and you can see stand-alone google example [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple?hl=tr-TR).

and in this doc. you can get information about Travel Modes.

> When you calculate directions, you need to specify which
>   transportation mode to use.  The following travel modes are currently
>   supported:
>
> ```
> TravelMode.DRIVING indicates standard driving directions using the road network.
> TravelMode.WALKING requests walking directions via pedestrian paths & sidewalks 
> (where available).
> New! TravelMode.BICYCLING requests bicycling directions via bicycle paths & preferred
> streets (currently only available in the US).
> ```

the Directions Service code:

```
var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom:7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: chicago
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  }

  function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
    var request = {
        origin:start, 
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        routePath = result.routes[0].overview_path;
        for(var a = 0; a< routePath.length; a++){
          // Your vector layer to render points with line
        }
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  }
```

The above code was taken from google api, i added some code there for you which you should have use used for your app.. main code for you is here:

```
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            routePath = result.routes[0].overview_path;
            for(var a = 0; a< routePath.length; a++){
              // Your vector layer to render points with line
            }
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          }
        });
```

i hope it helps you